# What is the best approach to print PDF from C#

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, batch-processing, acrobat

I have a bunch of pdf files (around 10K files) stored in a folder, all these pdf files are generated by a reporting tool and ready to be printed. Depending on the file name, I need to print each of these pdf files using a .Net program. I want to print pdf files as silently as possible, I don't want to read or modify pdf files.

Based on the research I have found following methods to achieve my requirement.

1. Use [RawPrinterHelper](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322091) to send each files to printer
2. [Invoke an instance of Adobe reader and print pdf files](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/598424/How-to-Silently-Print-PDFs-using-Adobe-Reader-and).
3. Use a [Third party pdf library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986878/net-library-to-print-pdf-files) to load document and print it.

For the past few days I have been googling to find out the best method to perform silent batch printing of pdf files, I could not come to a conclusion.

Are you aware of any opensource pdf library to print pdf files?

Comment: It looks like PDFClown has a printing sample : https://github.com/n9/pdfclown/blob/master/dotNET/pdfclown.samples.cli/src/org/pdfclown/samples/cli/PrintingSample.cs

Is there any reason it needs to be an open source library?

There are a number of companies that offer paid for tools (like Datalogics, yes I work there) that allow you to build this functionality into your own applications.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'll look at pdfClown. We have a printing application which uses pdfp.exe to bridge an old version of adobe acrobat reader to print pdf files. I'm rewriting this software now and I would like to avoid the dependency on Adobe reader. The reason to go with an opensource is to cut the cost.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @milez, the project which I was working got delayed and I'm no longer working there. Tho I did not implement the solution, I remember we were agreed to implement it using RawPrinterHelper because our printer supports it and we only need printing pdf files functionality.

Comment: using RawPrint;

    Printer.PrintFile("Printer Name", @"C:\Path\To\Print\File.prn");